# ASP.NET membership model for multiple Company accounts, each with multiple Users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Tyring to design a membership system for multiple company accounts, each with multiple users (as opposed to just unique users ala default ASP.NET Membership provider).

Seems like a very common scenario, but can find NO guidance.  **How is this usually implemented?**  ARGH!!

Company Account A [CompanyID]; User 1 [UserID]; User 2 [UserID];...

Company Account B [CompanyID]; User 3 [UserID]; User 4 [UserID];...

Can I use ASP.NET 2.0 Membership Provider (as is or modified?), or do I need to roll my own from scratch?

Planning SaaS application in ASP.NET 4.x Web Forms, C#, SQL Server 2008/12, shared DB + shared schema.  Customers will sign-up for Accounts (auto-provisioned), then setup their own users manually (or approve sign-ups).

I believe I understand the DB aspect (CompanyID + UserID), just not the Membership provider.  I plan to use email address as UserName (always unique), which will then identify which Company user belongs to, so no messing around with URLs needed.

Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to rollout your own, you can use [Membership.ApplicationName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.applicationname.aspx)   instead. All membership functionality is separateted by the application-name, hence it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Tim, Thank you for the quick reply.  I just spent a minute examining ApplicationName but don't fully understand yet.  Are you indicating I could set the ApplicationName as CompanyID?

Comment: Yes. It would allow  for example to use same email-adress or username for different users and so on. But i've never tried to use the application as customer so i've just commented.

Comment: Thank you again.  It looks like this would require dynamically setting ApplicationName in webconfig for every user login?  I'll look into it.  Hopefully will get some more comments re.  Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: You can change the `ApplicationName` directly with this property. But it's not thread safe(read the _caution_ part) which is a problem in an ASP.NET web application when two users would change the application-name concurrently. Changing the web.config would be even worse.

Comment: Yes, I now understand this will probably not work well, so will avoid it.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Noob_Ninja I have this exact requirement. Did you find a solution?